# how to store an array in local storage and then display it in dom

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to save the score of a game in local storage and then access it to display the saved score on my page
I am trying this

```
const savedScores = [];

function saveRecord() {
  localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(timeTaken));
  savedScores.unshift(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scores')));
}

function veiwRecord() {
  setBtnPopup((oldPopup) => !oldPopup);
  console.log(savedScores);
  return savedScores;
}
```

and then trying to display it like this

```
const scoreEl = savedSscores.map((score) => {
  return <p> {score} </p>;
});
```

Comment: should get from localStorage.getItem('scores'); first

Comment: change `savedSscores`  to  `savedScores` in the second snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can store arrays and other object types in localStorage using "JSON.stringify", as strings are the only data types that localStorage accepts.

```
var names = [];
names[0] = prompt("New member name?");
localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(names));

//...
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));
```

Then you can retrieve stored data with JSON.parse so you can use your array, object etc...

Comment: i am trying to display it on the page how do I do that

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan tried to explain what this code block does.

Answer (score 0):

All `localStorage` values are in string format, you need to parse the string array into array.

```js
function veiwRecord() {
    setBtnPopup((oldPopup) => !oldPopup);

    savedScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scores"));

    console.log(savedScores);
    return savedScores;
}
```

Comment: I already have in the saved function while pushing it to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the Item from localStorage as well in your veiwRecord method.

```
function set(){
        var sendJSON = JSON.stringify(timeTaken);
        localStorage.setItem('timeTaken',sendJSON)
    }
    
    function get(){
        var getJSON = localStorage.getItem('timeTaken');
        if (getJSON){
            timeTaken = JSON.parse(getJSON)
        }
    
    }
```